# XSLT: Creating a new parent node around elements with a certain attribute plus a final element with a different one

Tags: xslt

I have an original XML of the following structure:

```
<egXML>
  <measure type="Divison" n="1">
    <!-- The element with this attribute value can appear n times -->
  </measure>
  <measure type="End_Cycle" n="4">
    <!-- This element appears once after the previous elements with @type="Division" -->
  </measure>
  <measure type="Divison" n="5">
    <!-- This element with this attribute value can appear n times -->
  </measure>
  <measure type="End_Cycle" n="10">
    <!-- This element appears once after the previous elements with @type="Division"-->
  </measure>
</egXML>
```

The n elements with @type="Division" and the one with @type="End_Cycle" form one thematic block, so I would like to group them the following way:

```
<egXML>
  <section n="A">
    <measure type="Division" n="1">
    </measure>
    <measure type="Division" n="2">
    </measure>
    <!-- And as many as there are until the one with @type="End_Cycle" appears -->
    <measure type="End_Cycle" n="4">
    </measure>
  </section>
  <section n="B">
    <measure type="Division" n="5>
    </measure>
    <!-- And so on -->
    <measure type="End_Cycle" n="10">
    </measure>
  </section>
</egXML\>
```

I tried several approaches, but all resulted in the elements with @type="Division" in one section element only or in individual section elements.

Comment: Where does the measure Division n="2" in section n="A" come from? And what approaches have you tried already? Thanks for clarification.

Comment: If your processor supports XSLT 2.0 or higher, use `xsl:for-each-group group-ending-with`.

Comment: @michael.hor257k: Thanks, this worked perfectly my purpose!